# Notification about Database Change

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am trying a scenario in which I want to update my desktop UI running on different PCs with changes committed by any user. For example:

1. Application1 is installed on PC1, PC2 and PC3.
2. Assume all PCs are running this application.
3. Say User 1 on PC1 changes the data and commit to the database
4. the UI on PC2 and PC3 should be updated with changes without polling or pulling the data from the database.

Can anyone suggest a way to notify my middle tier service about the database change which then I can relay it to all registered client. Will SQL Notification Services or Service Broker notify when the table is changed (inserted/updated/deleted)? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: How do you expect to update your clients with changes to the database without communicating with the database?

Comment: Notification Services has been discontinued. Maybe look at query notifications? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx This will still require that the clients retrieve the new data somehow.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I will eventually pull the data from database but only when I get a notification from the server to pull. It looks like Query Notification could be an answer as suggested by Remus. I am planning to do this via a service layer which will propagate this notification to all registered client.

Comment: Its a little late response but finally I have implemented the query notification and it works fine if I register for one table moment I register for 2 tables I get notification from only the last table I register for notification. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Query Notifications](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) does exactly this. You will get a notification when data has changed on the server, you have to query the data again to refresh your UI. A simple implementation would be to use [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) and add an [`OnInvalidated`](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/source/browse/trunk/LinqToCache.vs2010/LinqToCache/CachedQueryOptions.cs) handler to the CachedQueryOptions object.

Comment: Thanks Remus for your suggestion and it sounds like a solution to me. I will implement it and see if it is working. Questions though, when you say Query Notification does it need any Service Broker stuff as well? Is it supported in SQL Server 2005 and going forward SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Query Notification relies on Service Broker for delivering its notifications. It's all described in the first link in my post.